# circular import landmines with Lettuce

Tags: python, import, project, pydev, lettuce

I have 3 projects set up in PyDev that all have eachother in their project references list. for illustrative purposes:

```
proj_f
    pack_foo
        mod_fooa (contains class Fooa)
        mod_foob (contains class Foob)
    mod_faa (contains class Faa)
    pack_fii
        mod_fiia (contains class Fiia)
        mod_fiib (contains class Fiib)
proj_b
    mod_bar (contains function func_bar)
    pack_baz
        mod_baza (contains class Baza)
        mod_bazb (contains class Bazb)
proj_t
    tester (what I'm running from)
```

For sake of example again, tester:

```
from pack_foo.mod_fooa import Fooa
from pack_fii.mod_fiia import Fiia
from mod_bar import func_bar
func_bar(Fooa(), Fiia())
```

and mod_bar:

```
from pack_foo.mod_fooa import Fooa
from pack_fii.mod_fiia import Fiia
def func_bar(fooa, fiia):
    if not fooa:
        fooa = Fooa()
    if not fiia:
        fiia = Fiia()
    fooa.do_magic()
    fiia.do_magic()
```

What I'm seeing is that some imports from foo will get `ImportError: cannot import name` in mod_bar when I call them from tester (crucially, some but not all).  If I run just mod_bar, the imports work fine, if I remove the dependencies and imports from mod_bar and run it from tester, it works fine; it only breaks if a subset of classes are imported from f in to both b and t and I run from t.  I've tried reading the docs on how import works and googling around for solutions, but I haven't found anything that has pointed me in the right direction.  I have a feeling this has something to do with some obscure part of the Python internals, but I don't know enough to know what that is.

I think this accurately represents what is going on, though there is an added layer of complexity involved in that the reference from `tester` to `mod_bar` is indirect (`tester` is a file I use to monkey around with my code as I work on it, while `mod_bar` is actually the Lettuce terrain file, and Lettuce is being loaded by some other modules that `tester` is calling.)  Can anyone provide me with at least some place to start looking for info on how to get past this problem?

Edit:

I was looking at this some more, specifically the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lettuce\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    terrain = fs.FileSystem._import("terrain")
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lettuce\fs.py", line 74, in _import
    module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\adminsetup\workspace\nytd_lettuce_lib\terrain.py", line 6, in <module>
    from session.session import Session
  ImportError: cannot import name Session
```

Could `terrain = fs.FileSystem._import("terrain")` in `lettuce.__init__()` be causing circular imports that are giving me these headaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, I was getting a circular import.  The problem is that when you `import lettuce`, lettuce.py executes, which then dynamically imports `terrain`.

What was happening with me was that I have a Session class that imports AbstractSession which in turn imports LoggerManager which contains a `logging.Handler` subclass which pushes log messages to a queue in `world`, and thus logger_manager does `import lettuce` to access `world`.  I also wanted all my tests to start by spinning up a Session object, so I have a `@beforeeach` method in terrain to start a Session before each test, which meant importing Session in terrain.

Of course, this means every time I import Session in any file anywhere, it's going to trigger the whole chain of events (Session>AbstractSession>lettuce>terrain>Session) that leaves session.session.Session uninitialized by the time terrain tries to load it up.

I think my best fix is to stick the log handler and log cache that are associated with world in terrain then have terrain attach the handler itself.  Luckily, this is an option for me since logging is global access.  This actually somewhat improves the compartmentalization of my framework as there won't be any code in the core libs that talks about lettuce, that will all be off in the lettuce lib.  Still, it would be best of lettuce didn't have these landmines built in...

tl;dr, avoid lettuce if you want to try to do anything more than really basic test suites.